# Figure placement from Sphinx to Latex/PDF

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I noticed that during conversion of rst files using Sphinx, figures may be placed before its original place within its rst file. This is performed to reduce number of pages in the Latex/PDF output file.

For example, I have the following rst format

```
content0
content1
image
content2
```

But the Latex/PDF output file is

```
content0
image
content1
content2
```

Is there a directive preventing this from happening?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Sphinx, but in LaTeX you can load the [`float` package](//ctan.org/pkg/float) and use `\floatplacement{figure}{H}` to keep the floats `H`ere (where they are in the code). However, in general the layout suffers from this.

Comment: I handle it now by adding a reference before a figure (e.g., `.. _my_figure:`) and reference the figure from the main text (e.g., `:numref:my_figure`). In `conf.py` (from Sphinx), I enable `numfig` by adding `numfig = True` in its own line. I will look for Sphinx directive to enable the `floatplacement` that you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: set `'figure_align':'H'` in [latex_elements](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-latex_elements)

Comment: from the [doc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-latex_elements): *If you don’t like this behavior, use ‘H’ which will disable floating and position figures strictly in the order they appear in the source.*